# PG Error Group By after migrating from SQLite

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, sqlite

I want to push my rails project from dev to production in heroku, and I just realized that heroku is using Postgre instead of SQLite, and I have one error that I still couldn't solve although I have looked at similar questions.

I have this query where each joggings have lots of attributes but I only want joggings with location_id and created_at that its location_id is distinct or not redundant, this query works fine with the results only show joggings where location_id shows only one time, but it's error in Postgre.

```
joggings = @current_user.joggings.where(together: true).select(:location_id, :created_at).group(:location_id)
```

Do you know how to solve this? Thank you very much

Comment: What is the specific error you're getting from Postgres?

Comment: ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::GroupingError: ERROR:  column "joggings.created_at" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function

Comment: Postgres is complaining you're trying to GROUP BY `location_id`, but you're not using an [aggregate function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/functions-aggregate.html) (such as `COUNT` or `SUM`, etc., though these don't work on dates).

Comment: try to add `created_at` in `group` clause: `.group(:location_id, :created_at)`

Comment: I use `user.joggings.where(together:true).select('location_id, max(created_at)').group(:location_id)` but it's just show `<Jogging id: nil, location_id: 1>, #<Jogging id: nil, location_id: 3>` without created_at